# Python: How come a large float turns into *inf* automatically?

Tags: python

*on Python 3.6.2, Win10-x64*

Just something curious that I encountered and couldn't quite explain.

In:

```
x = 10.0
for i in range(10):
    print(str(i) + " | " + str(x))
    x *= x
```

Out:

```
0 | 10.0
1 | 100.0
2 | 10000.0
3 | 100000000.0
4 | 1e+16
5 | 1e+32
6 | 1.0000000000000002e+64
7 | 1.0000000000000003e+128
8 | 1.0000000000000005e+256
9 | inf
```

**How come it just turns into `inf`?** Why doesn't it throw an exception?

If I replace the `*=` in the last line with `**=` for example, then by the second iteration it raises `OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')`, which makes sense (since it is a mere 10.000.000.000^10.000.000.000).

Does this mean that there is a kind of "soft" limit on floats that -- when exceeded -- turns them into `inf`? And if so, what is that limit and is it the same regardless of the arithmetic operation? And wouldn't that imply something like `inf == this_limit + anything`?

.

**ADD:**

I get that there is the `sys.float_info.max`. Is that the limit?

I just got an idea and tested some stuff out:

```
print(sys.float_info.max)
print(sys.float_info.max + 1)
print(sys.float_info.max * 2)
print(sys.float_info.max * 1.000000000000001)
print(sys.float_info.max * 1.0000000000000001)
```

This gives me:

```
1.7976931348623157e+308
1.7976931348623157e+308
inf
inf
1.7976931348623157e+308
```

This is strange to me...

Comment: Python isn't very consistent about whether it'll give you an inf or nan or throw an exception. NumPy is usually better about it.

Comment: IEEE 754 specifies returning infinity by default in this instance of overflow.

Comment: Can someome explain what overlfowed?  Why can't 1.00000 e+512 be stored?

Comment: `1.0000000000000001 == 1`

Comment: @JoshLee Ah, that makes sense, I guess. Still can someone elaborate a bit maybe?

Comment: It's a very good question. I'd love for the overflowing multiplication to raise, but there are backwards compatibility concerns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Go to source

If you inspect float operations implementation in CPython ([`floatobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/floatobject.c)), you can see that most operations are simply deferred to C `double` ops, like for example in [`float_add`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/floatobject.c#L537), [`float_sub`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/floatobject.c#L549), or [`float_mul`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/floatobject.c#L561):

```
static PyObject *
float_mul(PyObject *v, PyObject *w)
{
    double a,b;
    CONVERT_TO_DOUBLE(v, a);
    CONVERT_TO_DOUBLE(w, b);
    PyFPE_START_PROTECT("multiply", return 0)
    a = a * b;
    PyFPE_END_PROTECT(a)
    return PyFloat_FromDouble(a);
}
```

The result, `a = a * b`, is calculated on CPU, according to the IEEE 754 standard -- which proscribes the default result of `-inf`/`+inf` in case of an overflow (i.e. when the result can not be stored within the finite 32-bit `float` or 64-bit `double`).

Another thing to note is that any of the five floating-point exceptions defined in the IEEE 754 (like overflow) can either (1) produce the default value and store the exception information in the *status word*, or (2) raise `SIGFPE` signal if FP exception *traps* are enabled (see [GNU lib C docs on FP exceptions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/FP-Exceptions.html)).

In Python, traps are [never enabled](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Programs/python.c#L37), so the program runs in a *non-stop* mode.

### Multiplication overflow

That means, in turn, that the result of an overflow in the **`float_mul` routine above** will default to float `inf` (as defined in IEEE 754), and Python will simply return `PyFloat_FromDouble(a)`, where `a` is `inf`.

### Exponentiation overflow

On the other hand, if we inspect the [`float_pow`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/floatobject.c#L686) (shortened version below):

```
static PyObject *
float_pow(PyObject *v, PyObject *w, PyObject *z)
{
    ...
    errno = 0;
    PyFPE_START_PROTECT("pow", return NULL)
    ix = pow(iv, iw);
    PyFPE_END_PROTECT(ix)
    Py_ADJUST_ERANGE1(ix);

    if (errno != 0) {
        PyErr_SetFromErrno(errno == ERANGE ? PyExc_OverflowError :
                             PyExc_ValueError);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

we can see the result of your `x **= x` **would be `inf`**, if it were not for the additional *status word* (~ `errno`) checking -- and raising of the Python `OverflowError` exception in case the underlying `pow` overflowed.

---

In conclusion (as already noted here), Python is not consistent in handling floating point exceptions -- sometimes will return the default (from C/`libc`/CPU), and sometimes will raise a Python exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very elaborate and insightful answer. I feel like I should make this the accepted answer. But I already got the gist and important info from the other answer and accpeted it. I feel like it would be disrespectful to change it. I am not familiar with the etiquette on Stackoverflow regarding such a situation. Maybe someone could point it out to me. Anyway, this should be upvoted!

Comment: @JohnGalt, thanks, I enjoyed answering it. Regarding the accepting  another answer, maybe [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62252/is-it-poor-form-to-switch-accepted-answers) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93969/is-changing-the-accepted-answer-frowned-upon) discussion threads on Meta can help you decide. According to [SO intro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), one should upvote helpful and well-researched answers, and may accept the one he believes is the best solution to his problem.

Comment: Thanks for the Meta links. That makes sense of course. I switched.

Answer (score 7):

> How come it just turns into inf?

Because the result is too big for even the biggest finite float, so it overflows.

> Why doesn't it throw an exception?

Because Python isn't very consistent about when it'll turn an inf/nan into an exception. Some operations give exceptions. Some give inf/nan.

> Does this mean that there is a kind of "soft" limit on floats that -- when exceeded -- turns them into inf? And if so, what is that limit and is it the same regardless of the arithmetic operation? And wouldn't that imply something like inf == this_limit + anything?

Any result that would be bigger than 1.7976931348623157e+308 after rounding becomes an inf (or an exception, if Python feels like it). The exact limit is not expressible as a float; you cannot actually perform `this_limit + anything`, because trying to put `this_limit` into a float rounds it down to 1.7976931348623157e+308.

Comment: @AdamHughes: Because it rounds down instead of up. You need to add a bigger number to get it to round up and overflow.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that in your first reply

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. Also thanks to chepner in the comments to the original post I found the IEEE 754 exception handling standard of going to Infinity (but not beyond...). I guess there is a reason for why Python seems inconsistent with this. Maybe we'll find out.

Comment: The `math` and `cmath` modules at least should be consistent (with the possible exception of `pow`) about raising exceptions where IEEE 754 would have signalled one of divide-by-zero, overflow or invalid. The core arithmetic operators, not so much, unfortunately. It's hard to fix this without breaking stuff.

Comment: @MarkDickinson, seems like the inconsistency is introduced on CPython implementation level (see my answer).

Comment: @randomir: Yeah, `float_pow` was [fixed](https://bugs.python.org/issue7534) a while ago to better follow IEEE 754. In theory the same sort of fixes could be applied to all the arithmetic operations, but then you run into old code that's deliberately using `1e300 * 1e300` (for example) as a way to generate an IEEE 754 infinity.

Comment: @user2357112 I switched to randomir's answer as the accepted one because it goes more in-depth on the CPython implementation behind all this. I hope you are not offended. This does not make your answer less helpful though. Thanks again.

Comment: @JohnGalt: Not offended, though I deliberately didn't post source code for this answer. First, aside from the exception-or-not issue, looking at the code mostly just shifts the question from "why does Python do this" to "why does C do this", and the answer to "why does C do this" applies about as well at the Python level without going to the C level in the first place. Second, looking at the code mostly answers *how* a particular *implementation* produces its results, not *why* the *language semantics* are the way they are; [cont.]

Comment: different Python implementations have different code to implement float `*`, but they all have to implement the same language semantics.

Comment: @user2357112 That's fair. I guess this topic would justify a more extensive (philosophical) discussion. If enough people are interested, maybe this will continue.