# Why can x*x and x**2 return different results?

Tags: python, floating-point

```
x = 1.5 * 10 ** 156
print(x * x)
print(x ** 2)
```

`x * x` and `x ** 2` are mathematically equivalent. But when `x` is large, the former can return the result of `inf`, while the latter raise an overflow error.

```
inf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\diana\miniconda3\envs\py37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

Why can this be?

Comment: This might help: [Python: How come a large float turns into *inf* automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46432189/python-how-come-a-large-float-turns-into-inf-automatically). Converting `x` into a INT gives the correct value.

Comment: To get the correct answer, `x` needs to be created as an int in the first place, not converted from float to int. For example, try `int(1.5*10**156) == 15*10**155` - it's False. Or do `print(int(1.5*10**156))` to see the effect of the limited precision in the intermediate float.

Comment: note that the minimum value that triggers this difference is `math.nextafter(math.sqrt(sys.float_info.max), math.inf)`

Answer (score 6):

Why the difference between multiplication and exponentiation?

That is probably buried deep, deep in the mists of history, when Python was first written. Floating point multiplication in Python must follow the rules set up by the IEEE-754 standard, which has multiplication overflow to the special value float(‘inf’).

But for reasons now lost, whoever designed Python’s exponent operator, and the pow() function, made a different decision to raise OverflowError instead.

There’s probably no real logic behind the difference. Its probably just a case of somebody thought it was a good idea at the time.

[Source](https://discuss.python.org/t/how-may-we-avoid-overflow-errors/14606/3)

Comment: Note IEEE754 semantics have only been required in Python 3.11, previously it's been agnostic about `float` semantics.  It was happy with whatever your C compiler gave it for a `double` type (and on the vast majority of systems this was indeed be a IEEE754 binary64 float).  https://stackoverflow.com/q/70184494/1358308 has some more info